# Preg_match_all exact match with multiple words

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, word-boundary

I have a long list of keywords represented below with the variable `$skills` which contains `Shop Supervisor` but not `Machine Shop Supervisor`:

```
$text = "Machine Shop Supervisor";
preg_match_all("~\b$skills\b~i", $text, $matchWords);
foreach ($matchWords[0] as $matchWord) {
     echo "<b>MatchWord:</b> " . $matchWord.  "<br>";
 }
```

> Results: Shop Supervisor

How can I get the exact match of `$text`? so in this case there shouldn't be any results as `Machine Shop Supervisor` is not in the keywords list.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [anchors](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), not [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), so it is a full string match.

```
preg_match_all("~^$skills$~i", $text, $matchWords);
```

A space is a non-word character so it matched.

https://3v4l.org/OYlfD

Comment: Yeah! Thanks a lot.